# Restrict image only upload size in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, image-upload

How can I strictly restrict upload size for images only in WordPress? If you go to the Settings page, it will tell you Upload File Types and Max Upload Size.  I would like to keep the max upload size uniform for all except images.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a bit old but I had to recently do this for a project, maybe it can help someone.

**TL;DR**

Use this in your **functions.php**

```
/**
 * Limit the file size for images upload
 *
 * @param $file
 * @return mixed
 */
function filter_image_pre_upload($file)
{
    $allowed_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];

    // 3 MB.
    $max_allowed_size = 3000 * 1024;

    if (in_array($file['type'], $allowed_types)) {
        if ($file['size'] > $max_allowed_size) {
            $file['error'] = 'Please reduce the size of your image to 3 Mb or less before uploading it.';
        }
    }

    return $file;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'filter_image_pre_upload', 20);
```

**Details:**

You have to hook into the **wp_handle_upload_prefilter** filter, that allows you to modify the file array that is about to be uploaded (but before it's copied to the final location).

You'll receive a `$file` array, and the keys you'll need are **size, type,** and **error**

In the `$allowed_types` array you'll add the [mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) you want to allow.

In `$max_allowed_size` you'll set the maximum size you want to allow (this value is in bytes)

Then you validate that the file being uploaded matches your requirements, and if it doesn't you add the `$file['error']`.

In the WordPress code, if `$file['error']` is different from 0 it asumes it is a string with the error to display, and prevents the file from being uploaded.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible because you cant change `upload_max_filesize` in runtime. Check [this .ini configuration list](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php). It says that `upload_max_filesize` is [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Otherwise you could check file type with jQuery/JS *somehow*, change `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `memory_limit` or what ever you else suits your needs with AJAX (which seems to me sort of security hole) and then upload it.

Since you cant you cant change `upload_max_filesize` in runtime, it makes no sense to check if uploading file is an image or anything else, because file size is the same for all files. And by uploading I dont mean `move_uploaded_file()` function but the file transfer from client to temporary server files folder.